# No puedo ingresar al if con un dato ingresado por el usuario

Tags: java

Mi problema es que estoy pidiendo por teclado un numero para sacarle la raíz cuadrada, pero si es menor a 0 no debería ejecutarse el código, lo hago pero me arroja este problema:

**Problema**

```
Ingrese el radicando
-9
La raíz de -9.0 es: NaN
```

**Código**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RaizCuadrada {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num;
    float resultado;

    System.out.println("Ingrese el radicando");

    num = sc.nextInt();

    if(num <= 0) {
        System.out.println("Debe ingresar un numero mayor a 0");
    }else{
        resultado = (float) Math.sqrt(num);

        System.out.println("La raiz de " + num + " es: " + resultado);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Uummmm... Me acaba de funcionar perfectamente.

Comment: ¿Que IDE usas? no veo el problema, puedes realizar un Clean a tu proyecto y volver a construirlo, el código ya esta corregido.

Comment: Uso JCreator Pro, ya corregí el problema, es que tenía un residuo de un archivo viejo con el error, borre el archivo y lo volví a escribir

Comment: Ok perfecto, en realidad el código es correcto, por lo tanto no hay problema que solucionar ;) , saludos @darioxlz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el código se puede mejorar, conduciendo al usuario a entrar únicamente lo que se requiere para el cálculo: **un número positivo**.

Este programa determinará si la entrada es un número válido (en el caso de que el usuario entre otra cosa), y luego determinará si ese número es positivo:

```
    int num;
    float resultado;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        System.out.print("Por favor entre un número positivo: ");
        while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
            String input = sc.next();
            System.out.printf("\"%s\" No es válido. Por favor entre un número positivo: ", input);
        }
        num = sc.nextInt();
    } while (num <= 0);

    resultado = (float) Math.sqrt(num);
    System.out.println("La raiz de " + num + " es: " + resultado);
    sc.close();
```

**Prueba:**

```
Por favor entre un número positivo: f
"f" No es válido. Por favor entre un número positivo: -6
Por favor entre un número positivo: 0
Por favor entre un número positivo: m
"m" No es válido. Por favor entre un número positivo: 44
La raiz de 44 es: 6.6332498
```